# способ пройтись по папке с файлами , по порядку их расположения в ней

Tags: python, python-3.x

Господа , есть ли быстрый и удобный способ пройтись по папке с файлами по порядку расположения файлов в ней ? os.walk , os.listdir , ничего мне не помогло , я запускал по разным папкам , но результат одинаковый - файлы в сгенерированном списке выдаются в случайном порядке . В папке 26 файлов с именами _img_порядковый номер.png

код:

```
path = r"C:\Users\neir0\Desktop\studyV1\data\clean"
print(sorted(os.listdir(path)))
```

вывод:
файлы перемешаны

```
['_img_1.png', '_img_10.png', '_img_11.png', '_img_12.png',
'_img_13.png', '_img_14.png', '_img_15.png', '_img_16.png',
'_img_17.png', '_img_18.png', '_img_19.png', '_img_2.png',
'_img_20.png', '_img_21.png', '_img_22.png', '_img_23.png',
'_img_24.png', '_img_25.png', '_img_26.png', '_img_3.png',
'_img_4.png', '_img_5.png', '_img_6.png', '_img_7.png',
'_img_8.png', '_img_9.png']
```

ожидание:
список файлов ,согласно их расположению в папке

Comment: А что есть _порядок расположения файлов в папке_?

Comment: Что значит "по порядку их расположения в ней
"?

Comment: допустим в папке лежат файлы 1.txt , 2.txt , 3.txt ... ,они упорядочены по названию  . При использовании os.walk они меняются местами

Comment: Они упорядочены по названию только тогда, когда вы этого хотите (настройка файлового менеджера, например). А так, в вашем случае `sorted(os.listdir(PATHTODIR))` может помочь.

Comment: sorted мне не поможет , если имя файла не цифра . Я пытался его до этого использовать

Comment: Почему же? `sorted('024mksoq3') -> ['0', '2', '3', '4', 'k', 'm', 'o', 'q', 's']`

Comment: можете попробовать файлы с названиями [ '_img_1.png', '_img_10.png', '_img_11.png', '_img_12.png' ] , пожалуйста

Comment: лично у меня это не работает

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос: поместите туда свой код, пример входных данных, ожидаемый результат, полученный результат.

Comment: вообще , у меня в папке 26 файлов с именами _img_порядковый номер.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не привязываться к структуре в названии файла, то можно сделать так:

```
print(sorted(items, key=lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x)))))
```

Чтобы выглядел код приличнее, добавим функцию:

```
def get_num(text):
    return int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, text)))

print(sorted(items, key=get_num))
```

---

Сортируйте файлы как числа:

```
items = os.listdir(path)
print(sorted(items, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[2].split('.')[0])))
```

Этот код `int(x.split('_')[2].split('.')[0])` вытаскивает число из названия файла и приводит его к `int`:

- `_img_1.png` -> 1
- `_img_21.png` -> 21

---

Аналогично можно сделать через регулярку:

```
import re

def get_num(text):
    match = re.search('_img_(\d+).png', text)
    if match:
        return int(match[1])

print(sorted(items, key=get_num))
```

Comment: Спасиб , конечно , но я такое и до этого написал . Просто хочу сортировку "из коробки"

Comment: @SaharVkusni, а третий вариант?

Comment: хоть не из коробки , зато четыре способа и расписано

Comment: @SaharVkusni, зато первый (он же последний) больше всего подходит под "из коробки" :)

Comment: согласен , однако из-за доп.библиотеки вопрос весьма спорен . Она не в коробке идёт

Answer (score 4):

Порядок вовсе не случайный - это обычная лексикографическая сортировка. А хочется, видимо, так называемой Alphanumeric сортировки, которая учитывает входящие в строку числа именно в числовом порядке. В Windows есть функция сравнения строк `StrCmpLogicalW`, в GNU sort опция  `-V, --version-sort natural sort of (version) numbers within text`

Думаю, нетрудно найти реализации такой сортировки (alphanumeric или иногда natural sort) на Python - только надо следить, чтобы при наличии нескольких чисел всё продолжало работать.

Вот библиотека [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/). Пример из нижеуказанной ссылки

```
>>> import natsort
>>> your_list = set(['booklet', '4 sheets', '48 sheets', '12 sheets'])
>>> print ',\n'.join(natsort.natsorted(your_list))
4 sheets,
12 sheets,
48 sheets,
booklet
```

[Вот ещё какие-то реализации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669059/how-to-sort-alpha-numeric-set-in-python) (возможно, часть из них выделяет только одно число)

Comment: Добавьте пример работы с natsort